# A method that excludes NULL in sql and calculates hours

Tags: c#, sql

I have a small problem with which I can not afford the best, so I need some help from someone more experienced.
Namely:

I made a method that counts time from (ZPZ_Von) to (ZPZ_Bis), now there is a problem if in sql it appears zero on the same day for the time, how can I calculate the time, while ignoring this NULL What the program showed me.

means only how many NULL NULLs are shown in sql to calculate the time taken apart from the error.

This is my method that calculates the time when a mistake was made:

```
  private TimeSpan CalculateWorkingHours(List<PRAESENZZEIT> arrivals)
    {
        return new TimeSpan(arrivals.Sum(x => (x.ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay - x.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay).Ticks));
    }
```

this is the look of my database data:
[image]

At the moment, the method calculates all the data from the base including this null and converted 10:16, and I need a method that will skip if there is NULL in sql and calculate the time, in this case it would be right 6.41

Comment: Are you using Entity framework? DBNull checks should be made directly on business layer methods. Give more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You skip the null values with a where clause, something like this:

```
    return new TimeSpan(arrivals
      .Where(x => x.ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay != null)
      .Sum(x => (x.ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay - x.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay).Ticks));
```

Comment: Thanks! i put this :            return new TimeSpan(arrivals.Where(x=>x.ZPZ_Von != DateTime.MinValue).Sum(x => (x.ZPZ_Bis.TimeOfDay - x.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay).Ticks));

Answer (score 0):

If you fill your `arrivals` variable from your database you can maybe skip the records that have null values. Or when you created the `List<PRAESENZZEIT>` loop over it and set a default value for the `Nullable<DateTime>` fields and then calculate the difference

```
using(var context = new DataContext)
{
   var arrivals = context.TableX.Where(t=>t.Date1 != null || t.Date2 != null).ToList
}
```

Did not test this code wrote it from the top of my head